# Join lines between empty lines - python

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have a list of lines from a text file where i need to join lines which are consecutive and split from other line by empty lines. i get wrong output if i try to clear the empty lines first then join em by if loop of even numbers.

```
one
two

three
four
five

six

seven
eight
```

i am trying to read a file or list with lines to print the above as

```
one two

three four five

six

seven eight
```

the list looks like this `'\n', '\n', '\n', 'EMM - Freedom\n', 'MrSuicideSheep\n', '\n',`

**Edit:**

i did see the same answer in a similar question, but iam trying to do that thing in a list which i already did some operations. as i mentioned above the lists looks like this

```
['\n', '\n', '\n', 'EMM - Freedom\n', 'MrSuicideSheep\n', '\n'].
```

in order to get my expected output, i need to remove \n from all the words expect from which has the next item as '\n' later i could strip it to get rid of all the unnecessary n's. for now i removed all the \n' from all the sentences , leaving the empty lines to separate. so it now looks like

```
['\n', '\n', '\n', 'EMM - Freedom', 'MrSuicideSheep', '\n']
```

now may be i should remove consecutive \n's alone. lol sorry for making this complicated. btw i am actually working for this [git](https://github.com/thamizh5197/Youtube-mix-to-playlist-converter-python/blob/master/mix_text_to_playlist_text.py) , if u have a better solution do comment below.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip

Comment: i have no clue, trying to loop into the list and join the text between '\n'

Comment: can you add a list in question?

Comment: i did add, it looks like this lines = ['\n', '\n', '\n', 'EMM - Freedom\n', 'MrSuicideSheep\n', '\n']

Comment: first you could `strip("\n")` from every element on list and later you can `" ".join()` to create one string.

Comment: you can read all as one string  and try to split on `"\n\n"` which means empty row. And later you can `replace("\n", " ")` in every element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read all as single string - `file.read()` - and then you can try to split on `"\n\n"` which means empty line. And later you can replace `"\n"` to `" "` in strings.

Problem can be if there are spaces or tabs in empty lines.

---

Example

```
text = '''one
two

three
four
five

six

seven
eight'''

data = text.split('\n\n')
data = [text.replace('\n', ' ') for text in data]

print(data)
```

Result

```
['one two', 'three four five', 'six', 'seven eight']
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have to work with list then you could concatenate all strings from list and use previous code but problem makes `'\n', '\n', '\n'` (or more `\n`) which create empty lines and it would need `regex` to convert all `\n\n\n...` to `\n\n`

You can also use something like this. And it resolves problem with `'\n', '\n', '\n'`.

BTW: I use `io.StringIO` only to simply simulate file with data

```
text = '''one
two

three
four
five

six



seven
eight'''

import io

lines = io.StringIO(text).readlines()
print(lines)

results = []
row = []

for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line:
        #if not row:
        #    results.append('\n')
        row.append(line)
    else:
        if row:
            results.append(' '.join(row))
            row = []

# for last element this code has to be after loop
if row:
    results.append(' '.join(row))
    row = []

print(results)

print('\n\n'.join(results))
```

Results

```
['one\n', 'two\n', '\n', 'three\n', 'four\n', 'five\n', '\n', 'six\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'seven\n', 'eight']

['one two', 'three four five', 'six', 'seven eight']

one two

three four five

six

seven eight
```

BTW: if you uncomented line `if not row: results.append('\n')` then you get

```
['\n', 'one two', '\n', 'three four five', '\n', 'six', '\n', 'seven eight']
```

And yow may get `results[1:]` to skip first `\n`

Comment: i did see the same answer in a similar question, but iam trying to do that thing in a list which i already did some operations. as i mentioned above the lists looks like this

Comment: probably it would be simpler to concatename all strings from list to one string and use my answer. Problem can make only `'\n', '\n', '\n'` (or more `\n') which can create empty line in result. It would need to reduce it using regex.